# Slicing dataset according to values and assign first column entry as variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a dataset in a csv file in the following format

```
Category;Name;email;Functions;Owner_ID;Backup_ID
A;Bos;user1@mail.com;Driver;123;321
A;Bos;user1@mail.com;Driver;123;321
A;Bos;user1@mail.com;Driver;123;321
B;Nos;user2@mail.com;Builder;456;654
C;Kos;user2@mail.com;Engineer;789;987
C;Kos;user2@mail.com;Engineer;789;987
D;Los;user3@mail.com;Architect;100;1
```

I want to loop through it and at first, get the subset where the Category is the same. So, at the beginning, I want to select all the rows that have `Category` as `A`. After selecting it, I want to assign the first entry of each row as a variable. So, I want to have `Category=A`, `Name=Bos`, `email=user1@mail.com` and so on. These variables will be used for an analysis.

After I finish with `Category` `A`, I want to move to `Category` `B` and do the same, then `C` and so on.

Existing code is the following

```
for file in ${outputfolder}*.csv
do  
    awk -F';' 'FNR==1{split($0, a); next}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)print a[i] "=" $i; print ""}' $file
done
```

For each line, it assigns the entries of the rows as variables to the Name of the rows.

EDIT:

In the first iteration, I want to get all the items that belong in Category A:

```
A;Bos;user1@mail.com;Driver;123;321
A;Bos;user1@mail.com;Driver;123;321
A;Bos;user1@mail.com;Driver;123;321
```

After I get only these ones, I want to assign the first column values as variables.

So `Category=A`, `Name=Bos`, `email=user1@mail.com`, `Functions=Driver`,`Owner_ID=123`,`Backup_ID=321`.

After I get these assignments, I am going to do some operations. I only want the entries that belong to category A and not the others.

Then, I will go to category B and do the same. Same for the Category C.

The number of categories is not fixed. They can be 10 or 20 different ones.

Comment: when you say *`assign ... as a variable`*, are you talking about `awk` variables or `bash` variables?

Comment: fwiw, the current code doesn't perform any 'assignments'; the current code prints a string (the column header), a literal `=`, and another string (current field value)

Comment: I updated the question with expected result.

Comment: See the edit of my answer for what I think you now want.  If it still is not what you are looking for , you will have to provide a better explaination, as explained in [mcve].

Comment: You say "I want to assign the first entry of each row as a variable" but you assign all entries of only one row. You say "I want to assign the first column values as variables" but you assign all column values of only one row. Please provide definitions for "entry", "row", "column".

Answer (score 2):

If simple file content (no quoted newlines or semi-colons):

```bash
for f in "$outputfolder"/*.csv; do
    IFS=\; read -a cols <<<$(head -n 1 -- "$f")
    while IFS=\; read ${cols[@]}; do
        # do something here
        declare -p ${cols[@]}
        echo
    done < <(tail -n +2 -- "$f" | sort -t\; -k1,1 -s)
done
```

Passing `-s` to a sort that supports it, and sorting only on the first field, should retain most of the initial line ordering.

I assume header names are legal as bash variable names.

With your sample data, this will output:

```
declare -- Category="A"
declare -- Name="Bos"
declare -- email="user1@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Driver"
declare -- Owner_ID="123"
declare -- Backup_ID="321"

declare -- Category="A"
declare -- Name="Bos"
declare -- email="user1@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Driver"
declare -- Owner_ID="123"
declare -- Backup_ID="321"

declare -- Category="A"
declare -- Name="Bos"
declare -- email="user1@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Driver"
declare -- Owner_ID="123"
declare -- Backup_ID="321"

declare -- Category="B"
declare -- Name="Nos"
declare -- email="user2@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Builder"
declare -- Owner_ID="456"
declare -- Backup_ID="654"

declare -- Category="C"
declare -- Name="Kos"
declare -- email="user2@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Engineer"
declare -- Owner_ID="789"
declare -- Backup_ID="987"

declare -- Category="C"
declare -- Name="Kos"
declare -- email="user2@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Engineer"
declare -- Owner_ID="789"
declare -- Backup_ID="987"

declare -- Category="D"
declare -- Name="Los"
declare -- email="user3@mail.com"
declare -- Functions="Architect"
declare -- Owner_ID="100"
declare -- Backup_ID="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code that splits the headers line and the data lines.
But since the variables names are not known, they have to be kept in an array.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="input.csv"
if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: $file does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Build an array of the desired variables
firstline=$(head -1 "$file")
IFS=';' firstlinearray=($firstline)
numberofheaders=${#firstlinearray[@]}

# DEBUG
echo "----- HEADERS -----" >&2
echo "number of headers: $numberofheaders" >&2
for header in "${firstlinearray[@]}"
do
    echo "1 $header" >&2
done

while IFS= read -r line
do
    IFS=';' linearray=($line)

    # DEBUG
    echo "----------" >&2
    for item in "${linearray[@]}"
    do
        echo "$item" >&2
    done

    # Assign variables
    echo "----------"
    for (( i=0; i<numberofheaders; i++ ))
    do
        echo "${firstlinearray[$i]} == ${linearray[$i]}"

        # Put your code here to use the variables: ${firstlinearray[$i]}
        # and the values: ${linearray[$i]}

    done

done < <(tail -n +2 "$file" | sort)
```

- To run is normally, save it to a file and do: `$ script.bash 2>/dev/null`
- If you want debug logs, do: `$ script.bash`

The output of that is:

```
----------
Category == A
Name == Bos
email == user1@mail.com
Functions == Driver
Owner_ID == 123
Backup_ID == 321
----------
Category == A
Name == Bos
email == user1@mail.com
Functions == Driver
Owner_ID == 123
Backup_ID == 321
----------
Category == A
Name == Bos
email == user1@mail.com
Functions == Driver
Owner_ID == 123
Backup_ID == 321
----------
Category == B
Name == Nos
email == user2@mail.com
Functions == Builder
Owner_ID == 456
Backup_ID == 654
----------
Category == C
Name == Kos
email == user2@mail.com
Functions == Engineer
Owner_ID == 789
Backup_ID == 987
----------
Category == C
Name == Kos
email == user2@mail.com
Functions == Engineer
Owner_ID == 789
Backup_ID == 987
----------
Category == D
Name == Los
email == user3@mail.com
Functions == Architect
Owner_ID == 100
Backup_ID == 1
```

---

**EDIT May 28th**

If you want to process only unique lines, thus eliminating line duplicates, replace the last line of the code above with this line, which adds the `uniq` command.

```
done < <(tail -n +2 "$file" | sort | uniq)
```

Comment: I have updated the expected output in the original question. In essence, I want first to get all the entries that correspond to Category A, do some calculations there and then proceed with Category B and so on. The number of categories can vary and it is not fixed

Comment: The code provided loops through all the categories, sorted in alphabetical order.  Each line of the input file is therefore processed.  You will notice that the output is sorted by category, so your requirement is already fulfilled.  As a test, mix your lines into any order, you will see that category A is first, then B, and so on.